# C program strange behavior of printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm doing a simple implementation of the UNIX [wc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) command, and I have a very strange problem. If I remove the printf on line 49, the program doesn't work properly. I tried many things, but none of them worked. The program works, but the output is not what I need and want.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int *counter(FILE* file) {

    // Function counter - counts the number of lines, words and symbols
    int nsymbols = 0, nwords = 0, nlines = 0;
    char c;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(file))) {
        nsymbols++;
        if(c == ' '){
            nwords++;
        }
        if(c == '\n'){
            nlines++;
            nwords++;
        }
    }
    int count[] = {nlines, nwords, nsymbols};
    return count;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1) {
        int *counted;
        counted = counter(stdin);
        printf("\t%d \t%d \t%d\n", counted[0], counted[1], counted[2]);
    }
    else{
        int i,k, bool = 0;
        int total[] = {0,0,0};
        char c = ' ', w = ' ', l = ' ';

        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

            // Cheking if there are some options activated
            if(strchr(argv[i], '-')){
                if(strcmp(argv[i], "-")==0){
                    continue;
                }
                if(strchr(argv[i], 'l')) {
                    l = 'l';
                }
                if(strchr(argv[i], 'w')) {
                    w = 'w';
                }
                if(strchr(argv[i], 'c')){
                    c = 'c';
                }
                bool = 1;
            }
        }
        if(!bool) {
            // If none of them are activated from the user, automatically activates all of them
            l = 'l';
            w = 'w';
            c = 'c';
        }
        printf("%c %c %c", l,w,c);

        for(i = 1; i<argc; i++){

            if(strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0){
                int *counted;
                counted = counter(stdin);
                for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                    total[k] += counted[k];
                }
                if(l == 'l')
                    printf("\t%d", counted[0]);
                if(w == 'w')
                    printf("\t%d", counted[1]);
                if(c == 'c') {
                    printf("\t%d", counted[2]);
                }
                printf(" %s\n", "-");
            }
            else{
                if(strchr(argv[i], '-'))
                    continue;
                FILE* file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
                if(file == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
                    return 1;
                }
                struct stat checker;

                if(stat(argv[i], &checker) < 0 ) {
                    return 2;
                }

                if(checker.st_mode & S_IRUSR) {
                }
                else{
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", argv[i],strerror(EACCES));
                    return 3;
                }

                int *counted;
                counted = counter(file);

                for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                    total[k] += counted[k];
                }

                if(l == 'l')
                    printf("\t%d", counted[0]);
                if(w == 'w')
                    printf("\t%d", counted[1]);
                if(c == 'c') {
                    printf("\t%d", counted[2]);
                }
                printf(" %s\n", argv[i]);
            }
        }
        if(l == 'l')
            printf("\t%d", total[0]);
        if(w == 'w')
            printf("\t%d", total[1]);
        if(c == 'c') {
            printf("\t%d", total[2]);
        }
        printf(" total\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're returning and then using a pointer to a _local_ array from `counter`. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works with the `printf` in place is a coincidence: your program has undefined behavior, because you are returning a pointer to local. The memory allocated to local variables gets reused upon return from a function, so referencing that memory outside the function leads to accessing garbage values. Sometimes, however, a particular spot does not get reused because of the way the caller is using the stack. In this case, the program gives an appearance of working, but even a small change to the code could lead to producing incorrect results or even a crash.

Change your code as follows:

```
void counter(FILE* file, int count[]) {
    int nsymbols = 0, nwords = 0, nlines = 0;
    char c;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(file))) {
         nsymbols++;
         if(c == ' '){
            nwords++;
         }
         if(c == '\n'){
            nlines++;
            nwords++;
         }
      }
      count[0] = nlines;
      count[1] = nwords;
      count[2] = nsymbols;
}
```

and call this function like this:

```
int counted[3];
counter(file, counted);
```

This will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you! My project is done now, thanks to you! But because this kind of things I dont like C and I'm doing this only for school. Java all the way! :D

Answer (score 0):

The `count` array here

```
  int count[] = {nlines, nwords, nsymbols};
  return count;
```

goes out of scope and its lifetime ends after the function returns. You can make it static  or malloc the memory, both of which will extend the lifetime of the memory pointed to beyond the function's execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning the array `count` which is a local array. You can't do that. I will be undefined behaviour. Everything can happen!

It seems that the size of the array is fixed so you should declare it and pass it as an argument to the function counter().

Answer (score 0):

Either make the array static or create it using dynamic memory allocation via malloc or calloc... Because the array created in heap stays until the end of your program